# SQL creating a function that returns what step i'm in

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

i have an apex application that consists of different steps characterized by a table each (table project, table send_for_approval, table approval, table start_project, ... ect)m i want to create a function that returns what step of the project i am in, this is what i have tried so far

```
CREATE FUNCTION progress(my_id in number) return VARCHAR as
BEGIN
select project.id, send_for_approval.id, approval.id, start_project.id
from project
left join send_for_approval on send_for_approval.id_project=project.id
left join approval on approval.id_project=project.id
left join start_project on start_project.id_project=project.id
where project.id=my_id;
IF start_project.id is NOT NULL THEN
     RETURN 'Current step is the start of the project';
END IF;
IF approval.id is NOT NULL THEN
     RETURN 'Current step is approval';
END IF;
IF send_for_approval.id is NOT NULL THEN
     RETURN 'Current step is send for approval';
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, you will get an error, because you are doing a `select` query without fetching the results into variables; you need variables to handle the `id`s, thus checking the variables:

```
CREATE FUNCTION progress (my_id IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR
AS
    project_id              project.id%Type;
    send_for_approval_id    send_for_approval.id%Type;
    approval_id             approval.id%Type;
    start_project_id        start_project.%Type;
BEGIN
   SELECT project.id,
          send_for_approval.id,
          approval.id,
          start_project.id
    INTO project_id,
         send_for_approval_id,
         approval_id,
         start_project_id 
     FROM project
          LEFT JOIN send_for_approval
             ON send_for_approval.id_project = project.id
          LEFT JOIN approval ON approval.id_project = project.id
          LEFT JOIN start_project ON start_project.id_project = project.id
    WHERE project.id = my_id;

   IF start_project_id IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      RETURN 'Current step is the start of the project';
   END IF;

   IF approval_id IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      RETURN 'Current step is approval';
   END IF;

   IF send_for_approval_id IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      RETURN 'Current step is send for approval';
   END IF;
END;
```

Another way could be by implementing all the logics in SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION progress (my_id IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR
AS
   result   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   SELECT CASE
             WHEN start_project.id IS NOT NULL
             THEN
                'Current step is the start of the project'
             WHEN approval.id IS NOT NULL
             THEN
                'Current step is approval'
             WHEN send_for_approval.id IS NOT NULL
             THEN
                'Current step is send for approval'
             ELSE
                '...'                              /* do you need an ELSE ? */
          END
     INTO result
     FROM project
          LEFT JOIN send_for_approval
             ON send_for_approval.id_project = project.id
          LEFT JOIN approval ON approval.id_project = project.id
          LEFT JOIN start_project ON start_project.id_project = project.id
    WHERE project.id = my_id;

   RETURN result;
END;
```

As noted, this relies on the assunmption that this query is guaranteed to always give exactly one row; otherwise you would need to handle a `too_many_rows` or a `no_data_found` error.

Comment: It should be noted, a `SELECT ... INTO ...` expects **exactly** one row to be returned. If this is not guaranteed then you need to handle exception `TOO_MANY_ROWS` and `NO_DATA_FOUND`

Comment: Worked!!
i had to add select .... into but thanks a lot

Comment: i dun't know about the exceptions but i still need to figure out how to return 1 row only since the declaration of the 4 variables at the start makes the function return 4 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid joins altogether

```
CREATE FUNCTION progress(my_id in number) return VARCHAR as
  l_status varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT status INTO l_status
  FROM (
    SELECT 'Current step is the start of the project' status
    FROM start_project
    WHERE id_project = progress.my_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Current step is approval'
    FROM approval
    WHERE id_project = progress.my_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Current step is send for approval'
    FROM send_for_approval
    WHERE id_project = progress.my_id
  );
  RETURN l_status;
END;
```